# Calculation of bucks missing

Tags: arithmetic, fake-proofs

Lets say I bought $1000$ bucks from a friend of mine and $500$ bucks from another. Now I went to the market and there I accidentally lost $1000$ bucks. Ok then I did some shopping which costs me $300$ bucks. Now I have $200$ bucks remaining. I returned $100$ to the friend who gave me $1000$ and $100$ to the one who gave me $500$. So now I have to give $900$ to one and $400$ to another. If I sum up after giving there part to them, I got this. $900$(1st friend) $+ 400$(2nd friend) $+ 300$(Shopping) $= 1600$ it should be $1500$ why is it $100$ extra?

Comment: Please be informed that the ([tag:logic]) tag is about the mathematical sense of the word. This excludes questions about common-sense reasoning.

Comment: Why should it be 1500?  The 1300 is what you still owe which is different than what you spent shopping.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing extra, you just found some numbers that almost add up.  You borrowed 1300 net, lost 1000, and have 300 in goods, which adds up.  When you add the goods (which are an asset) to the two debts, you can get anything.

Answer (score 3):

spending money and returning money are different modes of transaction , one cannot add or substract to different modes like you have added the amount to return to the friends and the amount spent in shopping!